# AEM Trying to implement SocketIOServer

Tags: java, jsp, socket.io, aem

On AEM I am trying to implement a socket connection, I am using 
[Github URL](https://github.com/scalecube/socketio)
the maven project

```
SocketIOServer logServer = SocketIOServer.newInstance();
logServer.setListener(new SocketIOListener() {
    public void onConnect(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected: " + session);  
    }

    public void onMessage(Session session, ByteBuf message) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + message.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        message.release();
    }

    public void onDisconnect(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Disconnected: " + session);  
    }
});
logServer.start();
```

Error:

> The type new SocketIOListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method SocketIOListener.onDisconnect(Session)

Imported

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,         
                 org.apache.sling.commons.json.*,         
                 com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageFilter,         
                 com.day.cq.wcm.api.NameConstants,         
                 com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page,
                 org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils,
                 com.day.cq.commons.Externalizer,
                 java.io.DataOutputStream,
                 java.io.DataInputStream,
                 java.io.IOException,
                 java.io.InputStreamReader,
                 java.io.InputStream,
                 java.io.OutputStream,
                 java.io.OutputStreamWriter,
                 java.io.BufferedWriter,
                 java.io.BufferedReader,
                 io.scalecube.socketio.SocketIOServer,
                 io.scalecube.socketio.SocketIOListener,
                 io.scalecube.socketio.Session,
                 io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf,
                 io.netty.util.CharsetUtil,
                 java.net.Socket"
%>
```

Comment: Can you please post more of your code (including `import` statements)? The code you posted appears to be ok. The error leads me to believe that you did not override the `onDisconnect` method properly. That's why the compiler is complaining. One reason might be that the `Session` you are importing is not `io.scalecube.socketio.Session` but another `Session` type.

Comment: @Jens Hi thank you for your comment, I have added my imported data above. Also i just copied this right off of the github and had to search for the import statements in there examples.. But if you know a better maven project for socketIO please share

Comment: @Jens fixed that error but now i get Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext not found by io.scalecube.socketio [478]

Comment: It might be that either the netty or SocketIo library is not a proper OSGi bundle? So the SslContext class is not visible inside of the AEM OSGi environment

Comment: @AndreAlbert I did rebuild it, and the rest of the packages in the OSGI bundle do work just not this one